# Bash script that helps in opening documents when using terminal

Tags: bash, linux

I just finished creating my first bash script that helps me to launch documents from terminal using a pdf viewer. This is very helpful and fast (at least I think so) for people who don't use any files manager (and have lots of documents of course); therefore they launch their pdf viewer and documents from terminal.

I wish to upload the script on Github so any feedback, review, or tip on how it is or how to improve it before the upload is really appreciated.

Here is the script:

#### rdoc

```
#!/bin/env bash

declare -r CONF_DIR_PATH=~/.config/rdoc
declare -r CONF_DOC_DIR=$CONF_DIR_PATH/doc_dir
declare -r CONF_PDF_VIEWER=$CONF_DIR_PATH/pdf_viewer
declare -r TMP_FILE=/tmp/.rdoc_tmp


fn_generate_configs() {
    local doc_dir_path
    local pdf_viewer_name

    mkdir -p $CONF_DIR_PATH
    
    echo -n "Please enter your documents directorie's full path: "
    read doc_dir_path
    echo $doc_dir_path > $CONF_DOC_DIR

    echo -ne "\nPlease enter your pdf's viewer name: "
    read pdf_viewer_name
    echo $pdf_viewer_name > $CONF_PDF_VIEWER
    echo 

    echo Your configurations were generated succesfully.
}

fn_read_configs() {
    doc_dir=$(cat $CONF_DOC_DIR 2> /dev/null)
    if [ ! $? -eq 0 ]; then 
        echo Error: one or all of your configuration files are missing.
        echo Try -h for help.
        exit -1
    fi

    pdf_viewer=$(cat $CONF_PDF_VIEWER 2> /dev/null) 
    if [ ! $? -eq 0 ]; then
        echo Error: one or all of your configuration files are missing.
        echo Try -h for help.
        exit -1
    fi
}

fn_search_for_book() {
    local path
    local grep_opt=""
    local string_to_exclude=$1/
    
    if [ $i_status -eq 1 ]; then 
        grep_opt=-i
    fi

    if [ $r_status -eq 1 ]; then #Search recursively  
        for path in $1/*; do    
            if [ -d $path ]; then 
                fn_search_for_book $path
            elif [ -f $path ]; then 
                if echo $path | grep -q $grep_opt $book_name; then 
                    echo $path | sed "s|$string_to_exclude||" >> $TMP_FILE
                fi
            fi
        done
    else
        for path in $1/*; do
            if [ -f $path ]; then 
                if echo $path | grep -q $grep_opt $book_name; then 
                    echo $path | sed "s|$string_to_exclude||" >> $TMP_FILE
                fi
            fi
        done

    fi
}

fn_display_books() {
    local doc
    local founded_docs
    
    #Make sure a book was founded and TMP_FILE was generated
    founded_docs=$(cat $TMP_FILE 2> /dev/null)
    if [ ! $? -eq 0 ]; then     
        echo Error: no document was found with \'$book_name\' in it.
        exit -1
    fi

    echo -e "These are the documents that were found:\n"
    #Set output's color to red
    tput setaf 1
    
    for doc in $founded_docs; do    
        echo $doc
    done

    #Reset output's color 
    tput sgr0 
}

fn_count_books() {
    local doc
    local cnt=0
    local founded_docs

    founded_docs=$(cat $TMP_FILE 2> /dev/null)
    if [ ! $? -eq 0 ]; then
        echo Error: \'$TMP_FILE\' manipulation while the program is running are disallowed.
        exit -1
    fi
    
    for doc in $founded_docs; do 
        (( cnt++ ))
    done

    return $cnt
}

fn_final_book_name() {
    echo -ne "\nWhich one of them would you like to open: "
    read book_name
}

fn_generate_books_paths() {
    local path
    
    if [ $r_status -eq 1 ]; then
        for path in $1/*; do
            if [ -d $path ]; then
                fn_generate_books_paths $path
            elif [ -f $path ]; then
                 echo $path >> $TMP_FILE
            fi
        done
    else 
        for path in $1/*; do
            if [ -f $path ]; then
                echo $path >> $TMP_FILE
            fi
        done
    fi
}

fn_get_book_path() {
    local founded_paths
    local path
    local grep_opt=""

    founded_paths=$(cat $TMP_FILE 2> /dev/null)
    if [ ! $? -eq 0 ]; then
            echo Error: \'$TMP_FILE\' manipulation while the program is running are disallowed.
        exit -1
    fi

    if [ $i_status -eq 1 ]; then
        grep_opt=-i
    fi

    for path in $founded_paths; do 
        if ! echo $path | grep -q $grep_opt $book_name; then 
            continue
        fi

        book_path=${path}
        break
    done
}

fn_open_book() {
    $pdf_viewer $book_path 2> /dev/null

    if [ ! $? -eq 0 ]; then 
        echo 
        echo Error: \'$book_path\' can\'t be opened. 
        exit -1
    fi

    echo -e "\nOpening: $book_path"
}

fn_help_message() {
    echo Usage: rdoc \<options\> [argument]
    echo 
    echo Available options:
    echo " -h               Display this help message.                                                   "
    echo " -g               Generate new configuration files.                                            "
    echo " -r               Allow recursive searching for the document.                                  "
    echo " -i               Ignore case distinctions while searching for the document.                   "
    echo " -s               Search for the document and display results.                                 "  
    echo "                  This option takes a document name or a part of it as an argument.            "
    echo " -o               Search for the document, display results then open it using your pdf viewer. "
    echo "                  This option takes a document name or a part of it as an argument.            "
    echo "                  (Default)                                                                    "
    echo "NOTE:                                                                                          "
    echo "     When using '-s' or '-o' option in a combination of other options like this:               "
    echo "                                                                                               "
    echo "     $ rdoc -ris document_name                                                                 "
    echo "                                                                                               "
    echo "     Please make sure that it's the last option; to avoid unexpected behaviour.                "  
}


doc_dir=""
pdf_viewer=""
book_path=""
book_name=${BASH_ARGV[0]} #book_name equals to the last arg by defualt so the default option ('-o') will work.

#Options status
r_status=0
i_status=0
s_status=0
o_status=1 #Make -o the default option 


#Display help message if no options were passed 
if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
    fn_help_message
    exit 0
fi

while getopts ":hgris:o:" opt; do
    case $opt in 
        h)
            fn_help_message
            exit 0
            ;;
        g)
            fn_generate_configs
            o_status=0
            ;;
        r)
            r_status=1
            ;;
        i)
            i_status=1
            ;;
        s)
            book_name=$OPTARG
            s_status=1
            o_status=0 
            ;;
        o)
            book_name=$OPTARG
            ;;
        :)
            echo Error: an argument is required for \'-$OPTARG\' option.
            echo Try -h for help.
            exit -1
            ;;
        *)
            echo Error: unknown option \'-$OPTARG\'.
            echo Try -h for help.
            exit -1
            ;;
    esac
done

if [ $s_status -eq 1 ] || [ $o_status -eq 1 ]; then 
    #Make sure there isn't $TMP_FILE already generated from previous runs.
    rm $TMP_FILE 2> /dev/null

    fn_read_configs
fi

if [ $s_status -eq 1 ]; then
    fn_search_for_book $doc_dir
    fn_display_books
elif [ $o_status -eq 1 ]; then 
    fn_search_for_book $doc_dir
    fn_display_books
    fn_count_books
    if [ $? -gt 1 ]; then #If more than 1 book were found with $book_name in it
        fn_final_book_name
        #Clean any leftovers of $TMP_FILE to search properly
        rm $TMP_FILE 2> /dev/null
        #Make sure that the user chose an available document
        fn_search_for_book $doc_dir
        if [ ! -f $TMP_FILE ]; then 
            echo 
            echo Error: no document was found with \'$book_name\' in it.
            exit -1
        fi

        #Make sure that the user is specific enough about the book name
        fn_count_books
        if [ $? -gt 1 ]; then
            echo
            echo Error: More than 1 book was found with the name \'$book_name\' in it.
            exit -1
        fi
    fi
    
    echo -n "" > $TMP_FILE #Make sure $TMP_FILE is empty so it'll be usable in fn_generate_books_paths
    fn_generate_books_paths $doc_dir
    fn_get_book_path
    fn_open_book
fi

exit 0
```

Thanks for your time guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `#!/bin/env bash`

[Prefer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10383546) `#!/usr/bin/env bash`

---

`CONF_DOC_DIR` and `CONF_PDF_VIEWER` can be removed and use `$CONF_DIR_PATH/config` with contents:

```
CONF_DOC_DIR=...
CONF_PDF_VIEWER=...
```

Reading the config would become: `source $CONF_DIR_PATH/config`

---

`TMP_FILE` should be generated with `mktemp` so that we are guaranteed that file does not already exist

---

> `mkdir -p $CONF_DIR_PATH`

If value of `CONF_DIR_PATH` has one or more spaces, then multiple directories would be created. Quote the variable to prevent splitting: `mkdir -p "$CONF_DIR_PATH"`

---

> echo -n "Please enter your documents directorie's full path: "

Typo: directories

---

`fn_` prefix for function names is not necessary

---

> `for path in $1/*; do`

[Prefer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/55334/find-and-globbing-and-wildcards) `find -type f -exec ...`

---

> echo Error: no document was found with '$book_name' in it.

Quote escaping can be avoided with `echo "Error: no document was found with '$book_name' in it. "`

Comment: Thank you for the review, I'll fix everything of course and I really appreciate it.